# Swap a subset of multi-values in numpy

Tags: numpy, swap, array-broadcasting

Given a starting numpy array that looks like:

```
B = np.array( [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4] )
```

What it the most efficient way to swap one set of values for another when there are duplicates? For example, let

```
s1 = [1,2,4]
s2 = [4,1,2]
```

An inefficient swapping method would iterate through `s1` and `s2` as so:

```
B2 = B.copy()
for x,y in zip(s1,s2):
    B2[B==x] = y
```

Giving as output

```
B2 -> [4, 4, 4, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Is there a way to do this essentially in-place without the `zip` loop?

Comment: You should give an idea of the sizes of `B` and `s1` and `s2` and define exactly what you mean by efficient? Efficient with respect to memory or time?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> B = np.array( [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4] )
>>> s1 = [1,2,4]
>>> s2 = [4,1,2]
>>> B2 = B.copy()
>>> c, d = np.where(B == np.array(s1)[:,np.newaxis])
>>> B2[d] = np.repeat(s2,np.bincount(c))
>>> B2
array([4, 4, 4, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1), but it's going to be rather memory-hungry.  I'm not sure I have a better solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only integers that are between 0 and n (if not its no problem to generalize to any integer range unless its very sparse), the most efficient way is the use of take/fancy indexing:

```
swap = np.arange(B.max() + 1) # all values in B
swap[s1] = s2 # replace the values you want to be replaced

B2 = swap.take(B) # or swap[B]
```

This is seems almost twice as fast for the small B given here, but with larger B it gets even more speedup repeating B to a length of about 100000 gives 8x already. This also avoids the == operation for every s1 element, so will scale much better as s1/s2 get large.

EDIT: you could also use np.put (also in the other answer) for some speedup for `swap[s1] = s2`. For these 1D problems take/put are simply faster.